# Google Drive in ios application

Tags: google-drive-api, pdf-generation, ios-app-extension, google-drive-realtime-api

I need to add a link to Google Drive to my application. To clarify, I just want a single link, not access to the whole drive. I do not want the user to have to log in to their Google account. I have added a wkwebview, but when I open a document in Google Drive, the app crashes, because it receives a memory warning. I am afraid that users will have to log in due to the Google Drive API.

Could anyone suggest an alternative to the Google Drive API? Again, this is just to view documents on Google Drive.

Comment: You want the users to be able to access the data/file you are providing without them logging in with there own Google accounts. You can do it through the use of [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). A service account belongs to your application instead of the users and will allow API call even though the user will not login and the data will be requested on behalf of the user using your app.

Comment: i searched about it and generated a json file for my credentials but i have no idea where it was downloaded and i can not find it now